# What are solvers callback functions in pycaffe, and how can I use them?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

Looking at [this PR](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3020), I see that one can define `on_start` and `on_gradient` callbacks for `caffe.Solver` object.

```
import caffe
solver = caffe.AdamSolver('solver.prototxt')
solver.add_callback(on_start, on_gradient)  # <- ??
```

What type of objects are `on_start` and `on_gradient`?
What are these callbacks for?
How can one use them (an example would be nice...)?

Comment: Well... these have to be *functions* to be of any relevance. The only question now is, what kind of variables they got access to. E.g. AdamSolver.iteration or something like that (fantasy-example). **Edit:** checked some code. The callback function seems to live within the solver. So try to add some callback which accesses any of the internal solver variables and print it out.

Comment: @sascha I was hoping not to reverse-engineer this one... Moreover, when are then called?

Comment: Isn't this self-explanatory (start of iteration and probably after gradient calc but not sure about the latter)? The question though is: if you are asking what they are for, why you want to use them?

Comment: @sascha I would like some things to happen every epoch of train/validation... I am not sure these call backs are the right place to look... Besides, they are out there, they must be good for something. I was hoping for examples that might spark some ideas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Where and how are the callbacks defined?**

The callbacks are part of the Solver, and are thus defined in the [`solver.hpp`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/solver.hpp) file. To be exact, there is a [`Callback`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/solver.hpp#L78) class, which looks like this:

```
  // Invoked at specific points during an iteration
  class Callback {
   protected:
    virtual void on_start() = 0;
    virtual void on_gradients_ready() = 0;

    template <typename T>
    friend class Solver;
  };
  const vector<Callback*>& callbacks() const { return callbacks_; }
  void add_callback(Callback* value) {
    callbacks_.push_back(value);
  }
```

and a [protected vector](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/solver.hpp#L117) of such callbacks, which is a member of the `Solver` class.

```
  vector<Callback*> callbacks_;
```

So, this basically provides an `add_callback` function to the `Solver` class, which allows one to add an object of type `Callback` to a vector. This is to make sure, that each callback has two methods: `on_start()` and `on_gradients_ready()`.

**2. Where are the callbacks called?**

This happens in the [`solver.cpp`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/solver.cpp) file, in the [`step()`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/solver.cpp#L194) function, which contains the main worker loop. Here's that main loop part (with lots of things stripped out for simplicity):

```
while (iter_ < stop_iter) {

    for (int i = 0; i < callbacks_.size(); ++i) {
        callbacks_[i]->on_start();
    }

    // accumulate the loss and gradient
    Dtype loss = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < param_.iter_size(); ++i) {
        loss += net_->ForwardBackward();
    }
    loss /= param_.iter_size();

    for (int i = 0; i < callbacks_.size(); ++i) {
      callbacks_[i]->on_gradients_ready();
    }

    ApplyUpdate();

    ++iter_;
}
```

**3. Where is this used?**

This callback feature was implemented when multi-GPU support was added. The only place (that I know of), where callbacks are used, is to synchronize the solver between multiple GPUs:

The [`P2PSync`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/parallel.hpp#L85) class in [`parallel.hpp`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/parallel.hpp) inherits from the `Solver::Callback` class, and implements an [`on_start()`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/parallel.cpp#L287) and [`on_gradients_ready()`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/parallel.cpp#L325) method, which synchronize the GPUs and finally accumulate the all gradient updates.

**4. How to use callbacks from Python?**

As the pull request [#3020](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3020) explains,

> `on_start` and `on_gradient` are python functions.

so it should be straight-forward to use. A full, runnable example is shown in [this Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/HBadertscher/9c38dfebc91186887f11a4c2c80ead52#file-test_callbacks-py) I created.

**5. How is this useful?**

As the two callback functions do not take *any* arguments, you can't simply use them to keep track of the loss or similar things. To do that, you have to create a wrapper function around the `Solver` class, and call `add_callback` with two methods as callback functions. This allows you to access the net from within the callback, by using `self.solver.net`. In the following example, I use the `on_start` callback to load data into the net, and the `on_gradients_ready` callback to print the loss function.

```
class SolverWithCallback:
    def __init__(self, solver_file):
        self.solver = caffe.SGDSolver(solver_file)
        self.solver.add_callback(self.load, self.loss)

    def solve(self):
        self.solver.solve()

    def load(self):
        inp = np.random.randint(0, 255)
        self.solver.net.blobs['data'].data[...] = inp
        self.solver.net.blobs['labels'].data[...] = 2 * inp

    def loss(self):
        print "loss: " + str(self.solver.net.blobs['loss'].data)

if __name__=='__main__':
    solver = SolverWithCallback('solver.prototxt')
    solver.solve()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, I am finding it a bit difficult to implement. I managed the "hello world" example, but I am unable to take it to the next level: How can I inherit from `PythonCallback`? As far as I can tell this class is not exposed to python when importing caffe. What am I missing?

Comment: You're right, it isn't exposed to Python. I will have a closer look at it. Note that `PythonCallback` was renamed to `SolverCallback` in a PR that was merged yesterday.

Comment: @Shai see my edited answer - turns out you don't even need the `PythonCallback` class... sorry for the bad advice before.